# CreateAPIView overwrite POST to call model functions

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am making a banking system for a school project. It is my first time working with APIviews in Django and I have a problem.

I would like to be able to make a transaction between two accounts.

I have a model called Ledger. In the model.py I also have the two functions:

CreateTransaction: Is the function there is supposed to POST to the ledger table. Like an audit of the transaction. So it creates two rows in the database. One row for the to_account (to audit the credit) and one row for the from_account (to audit the debit)

CompleteTransaction: This is the function there is supposed to complete the transaction. That means that is take the amount and subtracts it from the from_account and adds it to the to_account.

```html
class Ledger(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    amount = models.FloatField(null=True)
    t_type = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    account_id = models.IntegerField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    customer_id = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete = models.CASCADE, default = None)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {} {} {} {} {} {} {}'.format(self.description, self.amount, self.account_id, self.t_type, self.timestamp, self.customer_id, self.transaction)


def CreateTransaction(description, from_acc, to_acc, amount, customer_id):

    legder = Ledger()
    Legder(
        description=description,
        amount=float(amount),
        t_type="CREDIT",
        account_id=to_acc,
        customer_id=customer_id
    )
    legder.customer_id = customer_id
    legder.save()
    Legder(
        description=description,
        amount=float(amount),
        t_type="DEBIT",
        account_id=from_acc,
        customer_id=customer_id
    )
    legder.customer_id = customer_id
    legder.save()


def CompleteTransaction(from_acc, to_acc, amount, fromnew, tonew, customer_id):
    account = Account()
    account.customer_id = Customer.objects.get(id=customer_id)
    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=customer_id)
    bank = Bank.objects.get(id=customer.bank_id)
    account.bank_id = bank.id
    Account.objects.filter(id=from_acc).update(amount=fromnew)
    account.save()
    Account.objects.filter(id=to_acc).update(amount=tonew)
    account.save()
```

my serializer:

```html
class LedgerSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'description', 'amount', 't_type', 'amount', 'timestamp', 'customer_id', 'transaction')
        model = Ledger
```

My view looks like this:

```html
class transaction_action(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = LedgerSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        description = request.data["description"]
        amount = request.data["amount"]
        from_acc = request.data["from_acc"]
        to_acc = request.data["to_acc"]
        customer_id = Customer.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        CreateTransaction(description, from_acc, to_acc, amount, customer_id)
        CompleteTransaction(from_acc, to_acc, amount, fromnew, tonew, customer_id)
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

It does not really work.. it just gives me
[image]

As you can see the fields in the post form is missing to_account and from_account.

please help me

Comment: What do you need right now? Just to add `to_account` and `from_account` fields to POST form?

Comment: To be able to complete the two function createtransaction and complete transaction. So the user POSTS the needed info and the two functions gets executed